# jQuery DataTable: flash.setAction is not a function

Tags: jquery, flash, pdf, datatable

I have some jQuery DataTable issues:

I get the following error when using [jQuery DataTable TableTools](http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/) to create an "export to PDF" button above my table:

```
flash.setAction is not a function
flash.setAction( 'pdf' ); 
(TableTools.js (line 1165))
```

My code is as follows, adapted from the example at http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/.

```
$(document).ready( function () {
    $('.attendees').dataTable( {
        "sDom": 'T<"clear">lfrtip',
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                {
                    "sExtends": "pdf",
                    "sButtonText": "Export to PDF",
                    "mColumns": [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
                }
            ],        
            "sSwfPath": "path/to/flash/copy_cvs_xls_pdf.swf"
        }
    } );
} );
```

Does anybody know why this occurs?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: One question: does the exact example at http://www.datatables.net/extras/tabletools/ work for you?

Comment: No, it doesn't; the exact example results in the following: 

flash.setAction is not a function
[Break On This Error] flash.setAction( 'copy' );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why, but I think this could be related to [ExternalInterface and swf not completely loaded](http://flexion.wordpress.com/2007/08/21/external-interface-tip/) when you press the button. Maybe `$(document).ready` is the problem: you should wait for every element in the page to be [loaded](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/).

Comment: The button doesn't even appear!

Comment: The button is a Flash button: are you sure your sSwfPath is right?